# Bootstrap card as button to display data

Tags: html, css

I have a custom checkbox, I have added a text, and I want the text to be align right side of a check box ,

Here is jsfidle: https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/ewpo0h1g/1/

Here is HTML

```
<div class="squaredThree">
  <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkOther" value="other"  >
  <label for="checkOther">Testing Check-Box</label>
</div>
```

here css

```
/* .squaredThree */
.squaredThree {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  margin: 10px
}

.squaredThree label {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #D7B1D7;
  border-radius: 4px; 
}

.squaredThree label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredThree label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* end .squaredThree */

.label-text {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

what am I missing in my code? any suggestion will be helpful thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the text outside the label field like below.

```
<label for="checkOther"></label>Testing check-box
```

```css
/* .squaredThree */
.squaredThree {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  margin: 10px
}

.squaredThree label {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #D7B1D7;
  border-radius: 4px; 
}

.squaredThree label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredThree label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* end .squaredThree */

.label-text {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
     <div class="squaredThree">
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkOther" value="other"  >
      <label for="checkOther"></label>Testing check-box
    </div>
```

**Solution 2:** You are applying styles for the checkbox using `.squaredThree label:after`, but the same it is getting applied for the label also. So use `before` property for applying the styles for the checkbox label like below. But in this case we were giving the label value here itself.

```
 .squaredThree label:before {
     content: 'Testing check-box';
     position: absolute;
     top: 4px;
     left: 30px;
     white-space:nowrap;
     background: transparent;
 }
```

```css
/* .squaredThree */
.squaredThree {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  margin: 10px
}

.squaredThree label {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #D7B1D7;
  border-radius: 4px; 
}

.squaredThree label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredThree label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* end .squaredThree */

.label-text {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
 
.squaredThree label:before {
  content: 'Testing check-box';
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 30px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  background: transparent;
  }
```

```html
     <div class="squaredThree">
      <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkOther" value="other"  >
      <label for="checkOther"></label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've limited the width of `.squaredThree label`, remove the `width: 20px` or increase it. Also add `padding-left` to it:

```css
/* .squaredThree */
.squaredThree {
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  margin: 10px
}

.squaredThree label {
  width: 130px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #D7B1D7;
  border-radius: 4px; 
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.squaredThree label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  background: transparent;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredThree label:hover::after {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
/* end .squaredThree */

.label-text {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="squaredThree">
  <input type="checkbox" name="optionsRadios" id="checkOther" value="other"  >
  <label for="checkOther">Testing check-box</label>
</div>
```